# Nested function invoked as method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, methods, nested, this

I'm reading the JS Definitive Guide 6th edition and I came across these lines:

> Unlike variables, the this keyword does not have a scope, and nested functions do not
>   inherit the this value of their caller. If a nested function is invoked as a method, its
>   this value is the object it was invoked on. If a nested function is invoked as a function
>   then its this value will be either the global object (non-strict mode) or undefined (strict
>   mode).

What I understand is that functions return global or undefined in strict mode as this' value. Also in methods , this refers to the object the method was invoked on.
Nested function called from function or method also has this object that refers to global or undefined in strict mode.

Given example:

```
var o = {                            // An object o.
    m: function() {                  // Method m of the object.
        var self = this;             // Save the this value in a variable.
        console.log(this === o);     // Prints "true": this is the object o.
        f();                         // Now call the helper function f().

        function f() {               // A nested function f
            console.log(this === o); // "false": this is global or undefined
            console.log(self === o); // "true": self is the outer this value.
        }
    }
};
o.m(); // Invoke the method m on the object o.
```

But what I don't understand is the following : If a nested function is invoked as a method, **its this value is the object it was invoked on**.

Can you give me an example where a nested function is invoked as a method and its this value references the object it was invoked on ?

Comment: Just do `o.method = f;` and you can invoke it as `o.method()`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly,

```
function f() {               // A nested function f
            console.log(this === o); // "false": this is global or undefined
            console.log(self === o); // "true": self is the outer this value.
        }
```

in the above code, `this` refers to `window` object. If you want `this` to point to the `o` object itself, then you should can use `apply, bind, or call`.

Like this `f.call(this)`

Comment: nice workaround to replace code like 'var that = this'

Answer (score 0):

If for example `m` method returns another object that has `n` method you can see that context of `this` in that method is that nested object and not parent object as `this.a` is undefined.

```js
var o = {
  a: 1,
  m: function() {
    console.log('Parent: ' + this.a)
    
    return {
     b: 2,
     n: function() {
       console.log('Nested: ' + this.a);
        console.log('Nested: ' + this.b);
      }
    }
  }
};

o.m().n()
```